# Multiple signature encryption with GnuPG

Tags: pgp

I'm aware that GnuPG encrypts for multiple recipients, but is there any way to build a multisig, say, 2 of 5 signatures with GPG?

So having a file encrypted for the following recipients needs at least two of the five to decrypt it:

```
gpg --encrypt \
  --recipient alice@example.com \
  --recipient bob@example.com \
  --recipient carol@example.com \
  --recipient ted@example.com \
  --recipient eve@example.com \
clear-message.txt
```

Comment: Terminology nitpick: A multisignature is about requiring a certain number of parties to **sign** a message. When talking about a system where multiple parties are required to **decrypt** a ciphertext, one would usually call it a 'threshold cryptosystem'. I don't think GPG supports this natively, but might be mistaken.

Comment: I would love to have that, maybe having shamir on top of  private key would do the job https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_secret_sharing